# WSO2 IS - Import Identity providers configuration from one IDP server to other IDP server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We have WSO2 IS set up as IDP for inbound SSO. As infra migration we rebuilt new WSO2 IS on new server. Is there any way to import all the SP and Identity Providers configured on ild IDP server to new ISP server?

Answer (score 1):

In Wso2 IS 5.3.0 you can download the resident IDP metadata.Additionally it supports uploading service providers and identity providers using standard SAML metadata files. Follow the below link for more information.

http://saml-metadata-featurer.blogspot.com/2016/11/saml-metadata-feature-for-identity.html

Comment: Thanks Pasindu! We are on WSO2 IS 5.0 so looking for the feature that I can use for this specific version of IS.